# Animate text content with JS

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

The following code makes a text content of a div to disappear while sliding it down.
How can I replace it's content from above while it still sliding?
My code is doing so without replacing new content and I just don`t know why?
My goal and idea are not just replacing text content, but doing so during an animation process.

```
var changeText = function(id, newText){
    item = document.querySelector(id);

    item.animate([
        // keyframes
        { transform: 'translateY(0px)', opacity: '1' },
        { transform: 'translateY(1px)', opacity: '0.9' },
        { transform: 'translateY(4px)',  opacity: '0.7' },
        { transform: 'translateY(9px)', opacity: '0.5'},   
        { transform: 'translateY(14px)', opacity: '0.3' },
        { transform: 'translateY(20px)', content: newText}
        
      ], { 
        // timing options
        duration: 500,
        
      });
}
```

Comment: It's going to be more complex. If you want to add new content while animating the old content out, then you need to add the content first, then make a transition from old to new and then remove the old content. The `content` property is a CSS property and does not change the content of an element. `innerHTML`, `innerText` and `textContent` to concern the content of an element.

Comment: Thank you. You are awesome! I wrote some code according to your suggestion. It works. Soon I will publish it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ignore 'type', 'formatNumber'. They are irrelevant to my question.

```
var changeText = function(id, text, type){
    item = document.querySelector(id);

    item.animate([
        // keyframes
        { transform: 'translateY(0px)', opacity: '1' },
        { transform: 'translateY(1px)', opacity: '0.9' },
        { transform: 'translateY(4px)',  opacity: '0.7' },
        { transform: 'translateY(9px)', opacity: '0.5'},   
        { transform: 'translateY(14px)', opacity: '0.3' },
        { transform: 'translateY(20px)', opacity: '0.3' }
        
      ], { 
        // timing options
        duration: 400,
        
      });

      window.setTimeout(()=>{
        item.style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(id).textContent = formatNumber(text, type);
        item.style.display = "block";
        item.animate([
            // keyframes
            { transform: 'translateY(-20px)', opacity: '0' },
            { transform: 'translateY(-14px)', opacity: '0.3' },
            { transform: 'translateY(-9px)',  opacity: '0.5' },
            { transform: 'translateY(-4px)', opacity: '0.7'},   
            { transform: 'translateY(1-1px)', opacity: '0.9' },
            { transform: 'translateY(0px)', opacity: '1' }
            
          ], { 
            // timing options
            duration: 400,
            
          });
    }, 400);
```

Comment: Thanks to Emiel Zuurbier

Answer (score 4):

You could start another animation as soon as the first animation is finished.
But before starting the second animation, you could change the text.

```js
var changeText = function(id, newText){
    item = document.querySelector(id);
    
    // item.animate(...) returns an Animation (refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate)
    let animation = item.animate([
        // keyframes
        { transform: 'translateY(0px)', opacity: '1' },
        { transform: 'translateY(1px)', opacity: '0.9' },
        { transform: 'translateY(4px)',  opacity: '0.7' },
        { transform: 'translateY(9px)', opacity: '0.5'},   
        { transform: 'translateY(14px)', opacity: '0.3' }
        
      ], { 
        // timing options
        duration: 500,
        
      });
      
      /* The Animation has an eventHandler 
        refer to here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation
        and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/onfinish
      */
      animation.onfinish = function() {
        // change text 
        item.innerText = newText;
        // and start the second animation   
        item.animate([
        // keyframes
        { transform: 'translateY(14px)', opacity: '0.3' },
        { transform: 'translateY(9px)', opacity: '0.5' },
        { transform: 'translateY(4px)',  opacity: '0.7' },
        { transform: 'translateY(1px)', opacity: '0.9'},   
        { transform: 'translateY(0px)', opacity: '1' }
        
      ], { 
        // timing options
        duration: 500,
        
      });
      };
}
```

```html
<button onClick="changeText('#txt', 'newTxt')">
Click me!
</button>
<div id="txt">
  Initial Text
</div>
```

Comment: I will check it late. Thx!!